# Is the accumulator in the reduce method an object with a key named total?

Tags: javascript

I came across some code in the beginner code [solution](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/certifications/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures-projects/cash-register/) for a freeCodeCamp [challenge](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures-projects/cash-register):

```
var register = cid.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    acc.total += curr[1];
    acc[curr[0]] = curr[1];
    return acc;
  }, { total: 0 });
```

I understand that the accumulator in a reduce function totals the values, but I'm confused by the usage `acc.total` -- as if it's an object containing a `total` key. Is that what's going on here?

Comment: it's just an object with key total, so if your desired output is object you can use it this way instead of using primitive values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial value of the accumulator is the second parameter passed (or the first item in the array). Because the second parameter was passed here, the accumulator, or `acc`, starts out as

```
{ total: 0 }
```

The accumulator *can* be anything, but in this case, yes, it's an object with a `total` key.

On subsequent iterations, the accumulator is the value which is returned from the *last* iteration of the callback. Each callback has `return acc`, so the accumulator is the same object on every iteration.

The code is (nearly) equivalent to:

```
var acc = { total: 0 };
cid.forEach(function(curr) {
  acc.total += curr[1];
  acc[curr[0]] = curr[1];
});
var register = acc; // same object as accumulator
```

Comment: Why only *nearly* equivalent? It looks like an exact solution.

Comment: The only difference is in the impurity of `acc` - its scope is now not only constrained to inside the `.reduce` callback (which is arguably a disadvantage, see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/388052/rationale-to-prefer-local-variables-over-instance-variables - with the `acc` outside, the code is very slightly harder to read). If there was *another* outside variable named `acc`, there'd be problems, but such a name collision is quite unlikely.